# How can I make my TinyMCE regex stop stripping out semicolons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, tinymce

I'm using TinyMCE and my image URLs contain `;` in some part of the URL.

i.e.:

```
http://www.example.com/ShowAsset;sessionid=23409234BASJDKLA?id=123123
```

When TinyMCE parses the CSS styles of the content, and executes a regex, it strips out the `;`, cutting in half the URL and making it an invalid IMG URL.

```
http://www.example.com/ShowAsset
```

The regex that is used to parse the styles is:

```
"\s*([^:]+):\s*([^;]+);?"
```

It totally makes sense that it splits the string by ";", since that marks the end of each style, but is there a way to make it clever and allow `;` in the URL?

Comment: Most of the time semicolons in URL's are used for malicious purposes, and unescaped it's a reserved character, much like `?` or `&`, most commonly used as a sub delimiter. TinyMCE probably removes everything after the semicolon because it's a common way to hide attacks.

Comment: lol nice info, didn't know that, unfortunately i'm not the one who decided this type of URL, i hate it too...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it is possible to change the regex which is used to parse the styles, change it to

`(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?`.

It will allow `;` in URLs.

See [this](https://regex101.com/r/rV1wP5/3)